# linked Model in CakePHP2.0

Tags: model, cakephp-2.0

i linked 3 models by $hasmany, all that works very fine, but when I try to find something from one column ( Table_2.Column2, Table_2.Column3 ), I get back the whole data from all tables.

```
$entlehnerArray = $this->Entlehner->find('all', array( 'fields' => array('tabe2.id','tabe2.titel','tabe2.vorname', 'tabe2.nachname')));
```

Does anyone have an Idea why it doesn't work ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used **'recursive' => 0**

```
$this-><yourModel>->find('all', array( 'recursive' => 0,  'fields' => array('Table_2.id','Table_2.titel','Table_2.vorname', 'Table_2.nachname')));
```